# How to create a patch in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, intellij-idea, patch

I've been using IntelliJ IDEA 9.0 Community Edition for some time after years living in Eclipse. One thing seems to be hard to find in it. I'd like to create a patch on some subfolder in my project. In Eclipse it is done using right click, Team, Create Patch.

Does anybody know how to do that in IDEA?

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-patches.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the **Changes** view. In the **group by directory** mode you can right click on the directory with changes and choose Create Patch from the context menu.

Answer (score 7):

You can do a right click Local History -> Show History and then choose a revision and click on patch button (the second from the left)

Answer (score 4):

From the top corner, click on Git -->patch--> create Patch from Local Changes

Answer (score 2):

In the **Local Changes** tab or the **Repository**(SVN)/**Log**(Git) tab of the **Version Control** tool window, select a change or changelist you want to create a patch for and click **Create Patch** from the context menu.

*P.S. relevant for all versions*