# How do I create a patch using svn diff in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, diff, patch

I'm trying to create a patch of my latest local changes for a project.  I've followed the advice from answers to another StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055474/how-to-create-a-patch-in-intellij-idea) and I can successfully create patches.  But the project uses Subversion and some of the files contain svn keywords.  For example in the Java class JavaDocs:

```
/**
  * @version $Id$
  */
```

The patches I've created don't seem to recognize these as keywords - the keyword substitutions are picked up as changes and appear in the patch, for example:

```
- * @version $Id: Example.java 5930 2014-01-03 14:34:42Z rlaidlaw $
+ * @version $Id: Example.java 5930 2014-01-03 14:34:43Z rlaidlaw $
```

I think this is because the patches are created using a standard diff tool rather than svn diff.  Is there a way that I can create a patch in IntelliJ using svn diff instead?  I've looked on the Subversion menu but can't find anything there.  Obviously I can do it from the command line but it would be great to use IntelliJ instead.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition, which has built-in support for Subversion.  I haven't installed any other Subversion plugins.